# Ways to determine the statistical significance between two independent datasets

Tags: python, statistics, analytics, hypothesis-test, kolmogorov-smirnov

Suppose `A` and `B` are two datasets. The datasets might have `100` features each. How do I perform hypothesis testing on these independent datasets to compare statistical significance?

I tried to write a code in Python. I have preprocessed both the datasets and I have tried using Student's `t` test considering the columns are normalized. The datasets are tabular data with continuous values and have performed one hot encoding on the categorical features. I tried performing `t-test` on a numerical column from the both datasets. But I can't seem to figure out how to perform on the entire dataset. I used the `scipy.stats` library.

Comment: Well, what's your null hypothesis?

Comment: My null hypothesis is that the two samples are drawn from the same distribution. I'm new to statistics and still figuring it out!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How will you compare the 100 features of one distribution to another. Column by column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Kolmogorov-Smirnov` test is a non-parametric statistical test that can be used to determine if two samples come from the same distribution.

One approach that you can take is for each of the features (columns) from the datasets `A` and `B` perform a `KS` test to check if they have come from the same distribution (using the `scipy.stats.ks_2samp()` function).

Th following code shows an example, where it uses couple of `2`-column datasets, namely, `A` and `B`. The first feature (column) of the datatsets `A` and `B` comes (are sampled) from the same (standard normal) distribution, but the second feature comes from different (normal) distributions (with different parmeters).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp

n = 100 # number of samples

A = np.hstack((np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=n).reshape(-1,1), \
               np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=n).reshape(-1,1)))

B = np.hstack((np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=n).reshape(-1,1), \
               np.random.normal(loc=20, scale=5, size=n).reshape(-1,1)))
```

If you plot the histogram of the features for the datasets, you will obtain a figure like the following:

[image]

Clearly the second feature is highly likely to be chosen from different distributions. Let's verify with the `KS` test.

```
for i in range(A.shape[1]):
    print(f'Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for feature column {i}')
    statistic, pvalue = ks_2samp(A[:,i], B[:,i])
    print(f"Test statistic: {statistic}")
    print(f"P-value: {pvalue}")

# Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for feature column 0
# Test statistic: 0.13
# P-value: 0.36818778606286096  # can't reject H0

# Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for feature column 1
# Test statistic: 1.0
# P-value: 2.2087606931995054e-59 # reject H0
```

As can be seen from above, using the `KS` test,

- we can not reject the null hypothesis (at `5%` level of significance) that the first feature for the datasets `A` and `B` came from the same distribution since the `p-value` is high (`0.368 > 0.05`),
- we can correctly reject the null hypothesis that the second feature for the datasets `A` and `B` came from the same distribution since the `p-value` is almost `0`.

You can use the same approach on your `100`-column datasets, by comparing them parewise.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a question for https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

But I'll try to give one approach using python code. This uses student's T-test or the [Welch T-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test) which is a stricter test as it doesn't assume that the variance of two distributions are similar.

Note that this checks if the means of the two distributions are statistically similar or not.

Example code in python for dummy data:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
arr1 = np.random.normal(loc=1,size=(10000,2))
arr2 = np.random.normal(loc=1,size=(10000,2))
print(stats.ttest_ind(arr1, arr2, equal_var=True, axis=0))
```

Output:

```
TtestResult(statistic=array([-2.13993016,  0.87158797]), pvalue=array([0.03237248, 0.38344366]), df=array([19998., 19998.]))
```

The above code compares column by column for equal mean and gives the p-value ( and t-statistic) for each.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the t-test on all the features of dataset as follows:

```
p_values = []
for i in range(df1.shape[1]):
    _, p_value = stats.ttest_ind(df1[:, i], df2[:, i])
    p_values.append(p_value)
```